# replace() fails for large strings

Tags: julia

I have the following code:

```
cd(joinpath(homedir(),"Desktop"))

using HDF5
using JLD

# read contents of a file
t = readall("sourceFile")

# remove unnecessary characters
t = replace(t, r"( 1:1\.0+)|(( 1:1\.0+)|(([1-6]:)|((\|user )|(\|))))", "")

# convert string into Float64 array (approximately ~140 columns)
data = readdlm(IOBuffer(t), ' ', char(10))

# save array on the hard drive
save("data.jld", "data", data)
```

Which works fine when I test it with the sourceFile that has 10^4 or less number of lines. However when sourceFile that has around 5*10^6 lines it fails at `t = replace(t, r"( 1:1\.0+)|(( 1:1\.0+)|(([1-6]:)|((\|user )|(\|))))", "")` with the following message

[image: errormsg]

Comment: You can always edit your question.

Comment: Could you file a bug report on https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia ?

Comment: Could you try using the Julia 0.4-rc1 version just tagged and see if the bug persist? I know the regex substitution library is bumped a version and some code around it refactored.

Comment: Which version of libpcre you are using ?  this may be the source of error  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1193524

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, and based on an older version of Julia. However, it would be useful to check if this works on a recent version. I recently tested this in  latest `0.5` version of Julia, and the code above seems to work correctly with 5*10^6 lines of 600 characters each. The entire operation takes about 5G of peak memory on my laptop.

```
julia> t=[randstring(600) for i=1:5*10^6];

julia> writecsv("/Users/aviks/tmp/long.csv", t)

julia> t=readstring("/Users/aviks/tmp/long.csv");

julia> length(t)
3005000000

julia> @time t = replace(t, r"( 1:1\.0+)|(( 1:1\.0+)|(([1-6]:)|((\|user )|(\|))))", "");
  43.599660 seconds (137 allocations: 3.358 GB, 0.85% gc time)
```

(PS: Note that `readall` is now deprecated in favour of `readstring`).